# Java Memory Leak in JDBC ResultSet/Statement

Tags: java, reflection, memory-leaks, annotations

I have a self-written mini library which is supposed to be working with MySQL db using reflection and annotations. For some reason my application, which uses its code has a memory leak problem. When I profiled it it detected a huge memory consumption by char arrays. Could anyone explain me whats wrong? (One of the function's code which causes memory leaks)

```
public List select(Class clazz, String condition, Object... values) throws Exception{
    Table tbl = (Table) clazz.getAnnotation(Table.class);
    if(tbl==null) throw new Exception("Specified class doesnt contain table information");

    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder().append("SELECT * FROM `");
    strb.append(prefix).append(tbl.name());
    strb.append("` WHERE ");
    strb.append(condition);

    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(strb.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        stmt.setObject(i + 1, values[i]);
    }

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList<>();
    while(rs.next()){
        Object o = clazz.newInstance();
        for(Field f : clazz.getFields()){
            Table.Column col = f.getAnnotation(Table.Column.class);
            if(col!=null){
                if(!f.isAccessible())
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                f.set(o, rs.getObject(f.getName()));
            }
        }
        result.add(o);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thank you in advance. PS I am not using List or elements in the List returned by this func for test purposes

Comment: Don't you have to close the result set and statement?

Comment: It should be closed automatically, as far as I know

Comment: Not sure about this.  Isn't that true only with java 7 new try with resources?

Comment: public void close() throws SQLException
Releases this ResultSet object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for this to happen when it is automatically closed.

Comment: OMG! You were right! Thank you so much))) Post your answer - Ill accept it

Comment: You really made my day. Spent 7 hours on identifying the problem. Couldnt debug my application locally, so had to set up remote profiling using EDGE. Never had so much pain( Interesting though what is meant in the documentation about automatic ResultSet release

Comment: I had the same problem years ago. I remember it was painful :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to close the result set and statement.